# Set custom date when testing web applications

Tags: date, testing, web, frontend

Is there a way to emulate custom date for frontend applications for testing purposes? Currently I am doing this by changing system-wide date, however, this has a lot of side effects such as license expiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about external tools but you can [monkey patch JavaScript’s Date object](http://me.dt.in.th/page/JavaScript-override/) if you have access to the code.